# ggplot2 - combining geom_bar and geom_line legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I can't seem to get my geom_bar and geom_line legends combined.  I know there are several discussions on this subject and I think I have tried most of the suggestions without success, but I don't think I understand the problem.  As I've spent a few hours on this and not made any progress I thought it time to ask the experts. Thanks for any help!

My data:

```
A <-data.frame("X"= 1:6, "New" = c(5,25,10,43,2,3), "Recaptured" = c(0,2,20,20,29,14), "Cumulative" = c(5,30,40,83,85,88))
```

My code:

```
A$X<-factor(A$X, levels=A$X)
A[A==0]<-NA
p1<-A %>%
  gather(key,value,New,Recaptured) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X, y=value, fill=key,  color="Cumulative"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Cumulative,group=1), size=1.25)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(), color="black")+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = 0.9)+
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab(NULL)+
  ggtitle("none")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.35))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  #theme(plot.margin = margin(t=4,1,1,1, "lines"))+
  theme(legend.direction="horizontal") +
  theme(legend.position = c(.25, 0.9))+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", linetype = "solid", color="black"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
p1
```

Current plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBaoc.png)

[image]

Comment: Well, one is a color legend, the other a fill legend. Can you clarify how they should be combined?

Comment: Thanks.  I just want them in the same box so I can display the legend horizontally above the plot title.

Comment: how about `+ theme(legend.position="top")` but remove the boxes.

Comment: Edward, that is very close, but the legends are still not combined, so there remains a space in between Cumulative and New.

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I basically just removed the vertical space between the legends by using `legend.spacing.y = unit(0.0, 'cm')` and changed the `legend.background` parameter to `element_blank()` since this parameter will create a box around each individual legend, which is not what you want, and added the `legend.box.background` parameter to draw a box around both legends at once.

[image]

```
A %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=X, y=value, fill=key,  color="Cumulative"))+
    geom_line(aes(y=Cumulative,group=1), size=1.25)+
    geom_col(width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(), color="black")+
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = 0.9)+
    xlab(NULL) +
    ylab(NULL) +
    ggtitle("My title") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.35),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.position = c(0.5, 1.2),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(size = 1),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(4, 1, 1, 1, "lines"),
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.0, 'cm')
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code but it's not quite what I need.  I need the legend items to be on the same line so I can spread the legend horizontally on a single line.  This plot is part of a multi panel plot and I want the legend to be above the main plot title.

Comment: All you need to do is add legend.box = "horizontal" to have the legends side by side. Not sure what you mean about the title, the image you uploaded doesn't have a title at all. Do you want a title called "none" or do you want no title?

Comment: Just modified the answer based on what you just said.

Comment: that is so close! But is it possible to eliminate the gap between Cumulative and New in the legend?

Comment: or, alternatively, increase the spacing between New and Recaptured to even things out?